# Android onClickListener strange behavior

Tags: java, android, events, user-interface, onclick

i'm trying to set a child click listener on my ExpandedListView, and i'm getting some strange results:

```
theList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "clicked");

        ExpandableListAdapter adapter = parent.getExpandableListAdapter();
        View v = (View)adapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "item: " + new Integer(groupPosition).toString() + ":" + new Integer(childPosition).toString(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        if (!((CheckedTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.check)).isChecked()){
            ((CheckedTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.check)).setChecked(true);
        } else {
            ((CheckedTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.check)).setChecked(false);
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

it sort of works.  when i check one of the items, however, another, additional item will also be selected, seemingly at random.  am i not doin this correctly?

Comment: still fumbling with this.  been several days.  i know other people are having this issue as well, but haven't found the solution.

Comment: the checked items are actually changing to random, different places as i scroll up and down in the list.  for instance, when i drop down group 0 and click item 0, that item is checked, but then when i pull down the group 2, it's item 5 is clicked but, up above, group 0 item 0 is now unchecked, and item 3 in that group is now selected.  pulling my hair out here.  this doesn't make sense.  and this exact code works from another example using ExpandableListActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue myself.  i ended up extending the adapter class and overriding getChildView and getGroupView and added a list of booleans to the adapter to keep up with the checkmarks.  probably not the most sophisticated solution, but works perfectly.